# Faulting application name issue with application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I have a code like shown below

```
if ((client == NULL) || (client->type == Leave_Agent)) {
```

but when i changed it with following code i am getting errors in event logs
the modified code is shown below

```
if (((client == NULL)|| (client->type == Leave_Agent)) && (client->type == 0)) {
```

errors in event log is

```
Faulting application name: test.exe, version: 8.0.16.0, time stamp: 0x5036427e
```

Can any body guide me how to fix this, which stopping my application.The && operator will make any issues in c++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wanted to move the () around so that you never dereference the pointer if it's NULL:

```
if ((agent == NULL)|| ((agent->type == SPUES_ntAgent) && (agent->type == 0))) {
```

Comment: it did the trick, but what is dereference , can you bit explain in a simple words , i would like to know the logical issue which previously we are getting

Comment: @vettori dereference just means taking a pointer and looking at what it's pointing at. That's not legal if the pointer is NULL, so normally in conditions like that you arrange the operators to ensure that evaluation of the expression stops before it gets as far as dereferencing things that might be NULL.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> if (((agent == NULL)|| (agent->type == SPUES_ntAgent)) && (agent->type == 0))
> ```

If agent is `NULL` then the left side of `&&` will always be true and `agent->type` will always be accessed. So a `NULL` agent ensures a `NULL` dereference.

You should change your code to ensure it only gets dereferenced **if it's not NULL.**

Comment: you meant the one mentioned by @Flexo?

Comment: @vettori Yup, that will do :-)

Comment: what is dereference means, what was the issue i was getting previously?

Comment: @vettori To dereference means to access what's behind the pointer. To access the pointed object.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can reach this

```
agent->type == 0
```

when `agent==NULL`.

I cannot comment on how to fix without knowing what behaviour you expect. At the very least you should make sure `agent` is not dereferenced if it is `==NULL`.